# Settings style form in app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, forms, settings.bundle

Is there an easy way to a Settings.bundle style form in an app? I have seen InAppSettingsKit, but I just want to create a form for data entry that has some nested pickers and other features simple to implement with Settings.bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to achieve, the settings screens are simply grouped table views with the standard styling.

With storyboards, the "static" content feature makes it even easier - this mode allows you to specify the contents of each cell right there in the storyboard, you don't need any datasource methods and can do it all via outlets. There is a good tutorial on Ray Wenederlich [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

Comment: it wasn't as easy as I would have liked in the end, I feel it would still be nice to be able to specify any form in a plist, but this did work.